# system verilog interface in module port list

Tags: system-verilog

I want to have the system verilog interface in a seperate file with different modports.
The interface has to be used by sv modules in other files.
Just like packages can be imported into module files, how can this be done for interfaces?

Thanks

Comment: Interfaces in this respect are very similar to modules. you can define them in any file and instantiate when they are needed.

Comment: module ab( iface.slave ins0 ); say the above module is in ab.sv & iface is in module iface.sv The above code is valid? Can I just compile this in vivado?

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Comment: module ab( iface.slave ins0 ); 

say in the above 
"module ab" is in "ab.sv" & 
"interface iface" with "modport slave" is in a separate file "iface.sv" 
The above code is valid? Can I just compile this in vivado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any import like you do with packages.

Just compile interface with modports in the same library of other sv modules.

---

Edit to add file examples:

**iface.sv**

```
interface iface (input logic clk);
  logic s;
  modport slave (
    input s
  );
endinterface
```

**ab.sv**

```
module ab( iface.slave ins0 ); 
endmodule
```

Comment: module ab(
iface.slave ins0
);



say the above module is in ab.sv & iface is in module iface.sv
The above code is valid?
Can I just compile this in vivado?

Comment: Files added, you can compile them